# Let $R=\{(x,y): x=y^2\}$ be a relation defined in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it reflexive, symmetric, transitive or antisymmetric?

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory

Let $R=\{(x,y): x=y^2\}$ be a relation defined in $\mathbb{Z}$. Is it reflexive, symmetric, transitive or antisymmetric).

I'm having most trouble determining if this relation is symmetric, how can I tell?

Comment: Would [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1449902/where-did-the-notation-bbb-z-n-bbb-z-came-from) be related to a recent meta-question somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The relation is not reflexive: $(2,2)\notin R$
2. The relation is not symmetric: $(4,2)\in R$, but $(2,4)\notin R$
3. The relation is not transitive: $(16,4)\in R$, $(4,2)\in R$, but $(16,2)\notin R$

Now, let's see if the relation is antisymmetric. Suppose $(x,y)\in R$ and $(y,x)\in R$. Then $x=y^2$ and $y=x^2$, which implies $x=x^4$. Can you now end proving the relation is antisymmetric?

Answer (score -1):

None. $(4,2) \in R, (2,4) \notin R, (2,2) \notin R$. It is anti-symmetric.

Comment: it is anti-symmetric though, isn't it? @BRICS-Fan

Comment: Could you expand a bit on that? I understand now why it's not symmetric, though. Thanks!